# '__neg__' implementation. i am learning magic methods in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, magic-methods

this is a polynomial class

```
class Polynomial(object):

def __init__(self, polynomial):
    self.p = tuple(polynomial)

def get_polynomial(self):
    return self.p

def __neg__(self):
    return tuple([tuple([-i[j] if j==0 else i[j] for j in range(len(i))])for i in self.p])

def __add__(self, other):
    pass

def __sub__(self, other):
    pass

def __mul__(self, other):
    pass

def __call__(self, x):
    pass

def simplify(self):
    pass

def __str__(self):
    return 'something'
```

if i use the below code, i am getting error that -p has syntax error. is there a different way to override the magic methods ?

```
p = Polynomial([(2, 1), (1, 0)])
print p
print p.get_polynomial()
q = ‑p; q.get_polynomial()
```

i am getting syntax error at q = -p

Comment: Read (and post) the *actual* error message.. follow the information presented.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `__neg__` method returns a `tuple`, instead of an instance of your `Polynomial` class.

Thus when you try calling `get_polynomial` it will happen on a `tuple`, resulting in an error stating that `tuple` doesn't have a method called `get_polynomial`.

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_polynomial'

As such your `__neg__` method must return an instance of your `Polynomial` class, like this:

```
def __neg__(self):
    return Polynomial([tuple([-i[j] if j == 0 else i[j] for j in range(len(i))]) for i in self.p])
```